# Change the name of our chat bot

Tags: discussion, chat

On other sites on the StackExchange network the bot in their chat room has a custom name and a profile picture.

[InterpersonalSkills.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) has the Introverted Meta Man and the [Extroverted Main Man](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-677/extroverted-main-man) to post new questions in the chat room.

In our [Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), we have a bot with the lame name [Feeds](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds).

Can we change the name to something more cool?

What should we name our bot?

Comment: Glarnak and Glarnak's prophet.

Comment: I worry it would make the chat seem focused towards established users who get the jokes (such as Glarnak) rather than a welcoming enviroment for all.

Comment: Featured by request, until there's a more pressing need. :-)

Comment: @Bellerophon As a new user, I think it would make for a fun inside joke for new users to get in on and feel like they're more a part of the community.

Answer (score 20):

[Slartibartfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slartibartfast) from **The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy** series is the ultimate Worldbuilder to me.

[Quotes](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0007550/quotes):

> Arthur Dent: Are you telling me you originally made the Earth?
>   Slartibartfast: Oh, yes. Did you ever go to a place - I think it was called Norway?
>   Arthur Dent: No. No, I didn't.
>   Slartibartfast: Pity. That was one of mine. Won an award, you know. Lovely crinkly edges.

Comment: Is there any way we can work that into a name which is more obviously a bot, per Olga's [answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5568/2252)?  I'm not entirely sure how much I feel the need to support people who don't recognize Hitchiker's Guide jokes on sight, but in the name of being civil, we should at least think about it =)

Comment: SlartiBOTfast?  Slartibartfast 2.0?  Slartibartfast News?  Auto-Slartibartfast?  Slartibartfast the Bot?  [Slartibartfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slartibartfast) Bot?  Link to somewhere else?

Comment: SlartiBOTfast amuses me =)

Comment: Marvin has a brain the size of a planet...

Answer (score 10):

[The Lost Builder](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-lost-builder-355cf7de7ec6)

(I don't actually care if we rename the bot, but if we do, well, we already have a mascot, and fan fiction based on it...)

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest we look to our chat's resident god Glarnak in this issue. I suggest the names **Glarnak** for the meta bot as, like a god, meta sends down commandments onto us which we must live by.

Comment: @Secespitus If there is it is from before my time. I'd assume James, Daaahwoosh, Green or NextTerran might know.

Comment: See [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3789/19951) for an answer explaining what appears to be the origin

Answer (score 2):

Since this website allows the use of nicknames/usernames, it would be nice if it were hard to confuse the bot with actual users. I personally would prefer the name to include 'bot'. Something like Bot, The Builder; WB Bot...

I definitely would not want the bot to be named after any fictional character or to be some kind of internal joke. All people here are, most likely, share an interest in fiction (and probably narrower genres of sci-fi and fantasy), however, we read different books and watched different films. We are not guaranteed to recognise a reference.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Monica's, Bellerphon's, and Olga's answers, I have come to three conclusions.

1. I could be convinced to use LostBot, WorldBot, or BuildBot (I loved the fan fiction!)...
2. But then I read the history of Glarnak (Forgive thy humble supplicant, Mighty Glarnak!).  I laughed so hard (you people had a ton of fun over the years) that I can't imagine anything else but Glarnak.
3. But, in the end, Olga's completely right.  It needs to be a Bot so new users aren't confused. (GlarBot?  BotNak?)

There's certainly a rich history to this site!

Comment: Where is this history of Glarnak?

Comment: @JakobLovern, [The Meme Reference](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3789/19951) and [The History of Glarnak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=glarnak&room=17213)

Answer (score -6):

As most of these ideas are bad, let me suggest a neutral name:

**B.O.B.**

---

As it seems to have lead to misunderstandings: This is not an acronym, it's just a neutral, simple, reference-less name. I think for worldbuilding it would be fitting to name the bot something that is no reference to any existing works in fiction but allow people to make up their own origin-stories and share them - building their own worlds.

Comment: ...what does it stand for?

Comment: @MCMastery nothing at all

Comment: While I understand the intention behind your name, it doesn't lend well to new users being able to identify it as a bot.

Comment: Microsoft BOB was a major flop. I suggest we do not repeat that. :)

Answer (score -7):

I would like to propose  CL4P-TP as another option

- the name comes from the game series *Borderlands*
- it's the name of the robot that helps the players

Comment: but what relevance does it have to worldbuilding?