# Congratulations, Worldbuilding!

Tags: discussion, questions

Congratulations, Worldbuilders.  Today we hit a total of 20,000 questions on the main site!  Good job on this milestone, everyone, and keep those questions coming!

Comment: For anyone who cares, [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/138219/maximum-personal-time-field-speed) is question 20,000.  Full Disclosure: It's my question and this may be just a strategy to increase views.

Comment: But how many do we have if you don't count all the ones that are on hold?

Comment: @AndyD273 Someone who knows how to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer could answer that.  Unfortunately, that knowledge has not yet been gifted to this humble servant of Glarnak.  (Translation: I'm too lazy to figure it out, but if someone else figures it out, please tell us).

Comment: Praise [Glarnak](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/the-many-memes-of-worldbuilding/3789#3789)!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyFQVZ2h0V8

Comment: Here are the numbers of total/non closed question https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/978030

Comment: @Sefa That is considerably more than 20000. I wonder how OP counted the questions and got to 20000.

Comment: I guess OP used the question count [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions) which doesn't seem count the same way. It's also possible that orphan answer are counted in the query as the only difference between question and answer is ParentId. It can also be due to migrated question. Lastly, I could have made a mistake in the query

Comment: Gryphon - (and @AndyD273) you wouldn't even need SEDE. Just [search for is:q closed:no](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano) and count the results. In this case, there are currently 15,142 non-deleted, non-closed questions on Worldbuilding.SE.