# Should I accept the best answer or the answer I use?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I've gotten tons of different answers that were really helpful on my [instant delivery time travel question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/188614/does-this-time-travel-delivery-service-cause-paradoxes-and-if-so-how-can-i-avoi), but I've come to a rather hard decision to make. I want to use one answer in the story, but another answer was really helpful and went into a lot of detail. So which do I click as accepted? The detailed one that will help others if they want to do the same thing, or the shorter possibly less quality answer that I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accepted answer is a mix of given answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/accepted-answer-is-a-mix-of-given-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Like Falling in Love:

There are rewards for giving the most clever answer, and there are rewards for giving the OP exactly what they really want. It's kind of like having the choice between a perfect guy who's funny, charming, and rich - or the one you actually fall in love with (but who might be short, bald, and have a terrible mother).

Voting selects the "best" answer, but you also need to reward the person who picked up on the vibe you had in your mind. Lots of upvotes give the perfect answer a reward. Upvote the perfect answer! But pick the answer that meets your needs the best to accept. Especially when the Mr. Perfect answer is showing it up. Every good answer deserves a shot at true happiness.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is that you can accept one and award a bounty to all those you deem worthy.

One of the reasons for starting a bounty is precisely to reward an existing answer.