# What are some statistics that prove Worldbuilding is the best Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm no good at SEDE. I doubt this will change. But I know, deep in my heart, that worldbuilding is by far the *best* Stack Exchange site.

So, let's crowdsource.

What are some statistics that prove WB.SE is the best Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Wooly, "best" is kinda relative to the person who says it . Still, I guess people who feel they are part of the WB:SE community would probably be happy seeing someone think it's the best SE in the whole world :).

Comment: @Tortliena, it's easy. Just build a world in which it's true by any metrics of your choice.

Comment: I'm a member at WB, Stackoverflow, Physics and Music. I'd be more interested to know how SE:WB compares to other worldbuilding (-related) forums elsewhere. SE is all these different subjects.. difficult to compare.  I wouldn't be surprised if SE:WB is quite unique in its own right. How SE:WB relates to others on SE, well I see a lot of common ground. It's a Q&A service, requiring people to *assign value* to questions and answers. In a sense, the SE culture is a bit of a *rat race*, imho. Also as a former moderator (elsewhere) I sometimes find it amusing how "peer moderation" works out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason why it's good to avoid superlatives (best, worst, greatest, least...) when asking a question — they're always subjective.

Worldbuilding is ***fantastic.*** You will find no Stack with greater creativity, greater imagination, greater flexibility, etc., than on worldbuilding.SE. And we're the only Stack (I believe) with its own, dedicated god: Glarnak[[1](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3789/40609)][[2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=glarnak&room=17213)]

And you won't find any of that by searching SEDE, which is only interested in network statistics. We're among the least populated stacks and therefore host among the least number of questions and answers. If we were top-ranked, it might be in negative things like number of questions closed as a percentage of questions asked or least-likely-to-upvote.

So, as with many of the questions asked here, it really depends on your perspective. Well, that and why you're asking. Why are you asking? Is there a pizza hanging in the balance or something? I'll flat-out invent a reason why we're the best if there's pizza at stake.

Comment: I read for a moment "we're the best pizza there". This alone would have been enough to consider this site to be the best all around :p.

Comment: Very insightful of worldbuilding.se history.

Answer (score 3):

Worldbuilding stackexchange is certainly amongst the least toxic ones, I know the music, fitness, vegetarian, economy, anime, biology, medical and programming stacks.

Worldbuilding + Vegetarianism stack exchanges are the only non elitist ones I know.

I don't know about statistics but there's plently of youtube videos for young programmers suggesting to avoid stackoverflow due to it's toxicity and elitism and in my opinion, for good reason.  I think the other stacks are similar.

But I don't see any youtube video saying worldbuilding.stackexchange is to be avoided.

In my experience, in terms of  who's  the least toxic and has the least elitism and gatekeeping, I would rank them as :

1st Worldbuilding

2nd Vegetarianism but it's dead now

3rd Economics

4th Anime

5th Biology

6th Fitness

7th Medicine

8th Stackoverflow

Comment: I tend to agree, but IMO I would place SO in the nth position, where n is the amount of stack exchange sites at the moment.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw  I've been on SO for years (2012?). Quality went down, but SO is still a treasure cove of information, on programming. I feel peer moderation has failed there. Far too many *gangs*, too many kids posting homework.. and far too many Python questions. But I still seek advice from it, when I'm looking for info via Google.

Comment: I believe [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) is definitely up there somewhere. Possibly at the top :)